# Multithreading on Hibernate's 'session.flush'

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jdbc

First of all, is this possibly ready-made?

> Hibernate 3.6 , JDBC batch_size 500 , using Hilo generator on the
>   200.000 entities.

In my example case, I have a request that takes 56 seconds, and I am creating 200,000 entities in the session. So, the `session.flush()` command takes 32 of those 56 seconds with only one CPU core at %100.

Is there a way to get the list of entities that need to be updated and create the SQL statements, say in four threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply `flush()` in different threads, because what `flush()` does is basically sending all pending SQL `INSERT` statements to the database using underlying connection. JDBC connections aren't thread safe, which means you would have to use 4 different connections and thus 4 different transactions. If all inserts need to take place in one transaction, there is nothing you can do here.

If you can live with 4 separate transactions, just create a thread pool and store records in smaller batches. Pool will distribute `INSERT` operations across several threads.

Also are you sure this will really help? I would guess `flush()` is not CPU-bound but I/O or network bound. However your experience is different with 100% usage, so I might be wrong. Also try optimizing `INSERT`s - using stateless session, raw JDBC/Native queries, batch inserts, etc. Spliting into separate threads is much harder.

Comment: im just printing time before and after the session.flush command and its taking 32 seconds . And as far as ive been searching around and stackoverflow , flush is where the sql statements are created, or is it also the command where they are all sent to the transaction on the mySQL side ?

Comment: @kommradHomer: during `flush()` SQL statements are created **and** sent to the database server. I guess that creating SQLs takes only a fraction of time. The real overhead is transferring the data and waiting for a result (database side).

Comment: and considering i do this test on localhost, its all about mySQL then